# Can StretchRect be used with DF24 or INTZ surfaces? Can DF24 or INTZ be multisampled?

Tags: direct3d, direct3d9, depth-buffer

Can you StretchRect from a DF24 into another DF24 (ATI specific)?

Can you StretchRect from a INTZ into another INTZ (nVidia specific)?

Can you create DF24 or INTZ as multisampled surfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it cannot be multisampled:

Sources:

http://discussms.hosting.lsoft.com/SCRIPTS/WA-MSD.EXE?A2=ind0801D&L=DIRECTXDEV&P=10986

> i'm using RAWZ
>   now i'v ran my app on laptop witch winXP and 8600go ... and all seems to
>   be fine
>   forceware version is that same for vista desktop and my laptop (differs by
>   operating system ofcouse)
>   strange ...
>
> The other thing that warps my mind is that the solution works only witch
>   nonmultisampled depth buffers witch suxx.

http://forum.beyond3d.com/showthread.php?t=53918

> But, there is a huge problem -> MultiSampling does NOT work !
>
> I need to turn off MultiSampling to bind the 'depthStencil_Surface' with my 'renderTarget'

If multisampling is not possible, I am not that much interested in StretchRect-ing it anyway. I wanted to use StretchRect to Resolve multisampled data.